# How to select the inner most node which contains an email?

Tags: xpath

From this sample HTML

```
<html> 
  <title>Our site</title>  
  <body bgcolor="#333366" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"> 
    <div id="Layer2" style="position:absolute; width:106px; height:134px; z-index:2; left: 20px; top: 340px;" class="info">info@systems.ca</div> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

I want to use XPATH to get my the most inner node that contains the email

I tried this:

> /*[contains(.,'@')]

But it selects the 'HTML' node. The name of the node should be anything (I know the '@' is a very week selection but I will then use regex to make sure the node contains an email).

### EDIT

In this case I want 'DIV'

Comment: May be /*[contains(text(.),'@')]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by selecting text nodes instead of `*`, then getting their parent nodes. The XPath expression would be:

```
//text()[contains(.,'@')]/..
```

This returns a collection of tags that contain text nodes, out of which at least one has an email address.

Comment: What if the email is contained inside an attribute and not a text node?

Comment: You'll miss it. Do you need to find it as well?

Comment: Yes, I guess I could use 'OR' operator with another XPATH

Comment: Yeah, you can OR it with `//@*[contains(.,'@')]/..`. Although all you get are parent nodes, not the attribute that contain the email address. You might want to skip the `/..` part on both expressions to help you spot the addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the most efficient, but try:

```
//*[contains(.,'@') and not(descendant::*[contains(.,'@')])]
```

or

```
(//*[contains(.,'@')])[last()]
```